# Asking opinion based questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I understand opinion based questions are discouraged on the main site. Is it ok to ask them here?

Comment: In short: no. Meta is meant for general discussions about the main site.

Comment: However, if they're opinion based questions *about the site as a whole or its working*, of course you can!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Blue said: Meta is meant for general discussions about the main site.

If your opinion based question is something like

> Do you think this site is getting more rude to new comers?

That's perfectly on topic.

If your opinion based question is something like

> Do you think quantum computing will become the next big thing?

That's not on topic.

(Sorry for the poor example questions; but hopefully they get the idea across.)